# How do you set the value of more than 1 parameter of an object containing enums?

Tags: vb.net, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I am using Protobuf-net in VB.NET to pass motor commands from one computer to another. Below is a sample of my proto file, which contains two enums, `CommandAction` and `MotorChoice`. I'd like to set a value for each of them on one computer and retrieve these values from another computer.

```
Public Class RemoteControl

<ProtoContract>
Public Class Command

    <ProtoContract>
    Enum CommandAction
        <ProtoMember(1)>
        HOME_MOTOR
        <ProtoMember(2)>
        MOVE_ABS
    End Enum

    <ProtoContract>
    Enum MotorChoice
        <ProtoMember(1)>
         MOTOR1
        <ProtoMember(2)>
         MOTOR2
    End Enum
End Class
End Class
```

I am running into issues trying to set a value for both the action and the motor choice. When I only had to set one parameter the below statements worked

```
Dim myProto As New RemoteControl.Command.CommandAction
myProto= RemoteControl.Command.CommandAction.HOME_MOTOR
```

When trying to set two parameters I tried the following:

```
 Dim myProtoExpanded As New RemoteControl.Command
 myProtoExpanded.CommandAction = RemoteControl.Command.CommandAction.HOME_MOTOR
 myProtoExpanded.MotorChoice= RemoteControl.Command.MotorChoice.MOTOR1
```

The compiler throws out errors, saying both left hand sides are types and cannot be used as expressions. What is the correct way to set the values of the two parameters of `myProtoExpanded` before serializing? I'd like to send one object that has information about both enums

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined the Enum datatype, but you did not add data members of that enum into the Command class.

```
Public Class Command
   Enum CommandAction
      ... 
   End Enum
   Enum MotorChoice
        ....
   End Enum

   Public action as CommandAction
   Public motor as MotorChoice

End Class

myProtoExpanded.action = RemoteControl.Command.CommandAction.HOME_MOTOR
myProtoExpanded.motor = RemoteControl.Command.MotorChoice.MOTOR1
```